# Create a function to capitalise first letter of the first word only in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a function that will capitalise the first letter only of a string, not every word.

Essentially it will do the following:

**One Two THREE FoUr**

will become

**One two three four**

I've found plenty of help relating to capitalising the first letter of every word in a string but cant find anything for just the first letter.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Malcolm.

Comment: Substring the first letter use UPPER, substring the whole string minus the first letter use LOWER then concat them together

Answer (score 6):

Use `Left`, `Substring` and `Len` string functions to do this.

```
SELECT Upper(LEFT('One Two THREE FoUr', 1)) 
       + Lower(Substring('One Two THREE FoUr', 2, Len('One Two THREE FoUr')))
```

**Result :** `One two three four`

Alternate to `Substring` is `RIGHT` function

```
SELECT Upper(LEFT('One Two THREE FoUr', 1)) 
       + Lower(Right('One Two THREE FoUr', Len('One Two THREE FoUr')-1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It works excellent but how do I create a function using the above?

Comment: Please google and learn about the CREATE FUNCTION command in SQL.

Comment: Not sure why I got **downvote**

Comment: Thank you for your help Tab.  I did search on how to create a function and just couldn't quite get it to work but I'll have a another look. Thanks again.